# How do I mark a .txt file as "not executable"?

Tags: python, cron, openshift

I am hosting a text file on OpenShift inside the cron/minutely directory. The server is trying to run the text file every minute, only I don't want it to: all I want the text file to do is stay on the server so I can save useful information inside it.

How do I tell the server that I want it to ignore the text inside the file instead of running it as code? Is there a way to do it by adding a specific "shebang" line at the beginning? Is it even possible to keep the text file in the cron/minutely directory without it being executed?

Thank you.

Comment: Wait. Why would you put a text file into cron minutely directory? Cron assumes that whatever you put there is a sript/executable you would like to have executed every minute. So the answer to your question would be "don't put the file there". But the question is what are you actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this as the first line of the text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/true
```

That's a sort of fake [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line.  It means that if the file is executed, the "interpreter" to "run" the file is the `true` program, which is a trivial program which does nothing but return the status code for success (0).

Therefore, a `true` shebang will make any file "successfully" execute, but do nothing.

Please don't take this to mean that leaving data files in a directory meant for executables is a good idea; it's not.  This is just a hack of last resort.

Comment: And why do you think it's a bad idea to leave data files in a directory meant for executables? Is it because it wastes computing power, or is there some other reason?

Comment: @loic17: because it is not intuitive for future maintainers of the system, mostly.

Comment: @loic17: moreover it doesn't make much sense